# How to give button or recyclerview item's style programmatically using style attribute in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-styles, android-attributes, declare-styleable

I defined two attributes for button style like

```
<!-- attrs.xml-->
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomButton">
    <attr name="rectangleCustomButtonStatus1" format="reference" />
    <attr name="rectangleCustomButtonStatus2" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>

<!-- styles.xml -->
 <style name="AppTheme">
       <item name="rectangleCustomButtonStatus1">@style/GoldButtonStyle</item>
       <item name="rectangleCustomButtonStatus2">@style/WhiteButtonStyle</item>
       ....
 </style>
```

GoldButtonStyle and WhiteButtonStyle  i defined in style.xml itself.

now i am applying above defined attribute syle in xml like

```
 <Button
  style="?attr/rectangleCustomButtonStatus1"
  ..... />
```

I am using Recyclerview, Recyclerview item has one button. Button text will be changed based on status like **pending**, **completed**. I want to set attribute style like if status is **pending** then use **rectangleCustomButtonStatus1** and if status is **completed** then use **rectangleCustomButtonStatus2**.

So how can i give style attribute programmatically?
same thing i have to do for recyclerview itemview's item. so how can i achieve this?

Comment: if you want to pass style programatically then use this in your logic:
R.style.rectangleCustomButtonStatus1

Comment: have you tried @Umair ?? because i tried every possible solution. and at the end i use two button for temporary solution. but i want it with only one button.

Comment: I have used this approach in dialogs. But i am sure it will work on buttons too. what have you tried so far ? can you post your adapter code ?

Comment: One more thing that R.style.rectangleCustomButtonStatus1 is not style its attribute which i defined in attrs.xml. so you can't refer with R.style

Comment: yes you are right, I am just giving you the idea that how it is done. By the way if you want to change basic design of your button you can do that with if else condition too in your code. Because styles can be applied to a View at initialization phase.

Comment: ya i can achieve with giving background propery but i have to do attribute only. because i have to give multiple color support for app. So for that i just remain to define different color AppTheme.